# postgresql slow query performance optimization

Tags: performance, postgresql, explain

As you may notice most of the time (78.7%) is taken up in a Seq Scan over the "oscar_two" table.

[EXPLAIN ANALYZE SNAPSHOT](http://explain.depesz.com/s/3eo)

Comment: Could you include your query in the question?

Comment: Sure @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister. Doing that in a bit.